# Fitting parametric survival curves on Kaplan Meier probabilities in aggregate data

Tags: distributions, survival, curve-fitting, lognormal-distribution, weibull-distribution

Lets suppose I have **aggregate** survival probabilities (NOT individual level data) from Kaplan Meier curves.  I would like to curve fit different "types" of distribution like exponential, weibull, log-normal, and log-logistic on this curve so that I can extrapolate.

Below is the sample data derived from KM for aggregated data.

```
surv <- c(0.92,0.86,0.80,0.77,0.73,0.70,0.68,0.63,0.61,0.59,0.57)
```

[image]

Below are my questions:

1. How would I curve fit the data to the aforementioned distributions, to derive parameters such as scale and shape in case of weibull?
2. Any illustrative examples in `Excel` or `R` would very helpful.

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't use a generic non-linear curve fitting function, like `nls` in R?

Comment: @EdM, non-linear curving fitting algorithm always provide illogical curves, a better fit would be to fit an assumed probability distribution based on domain knowledge.

Comment: The `survreg` function in R's survival package will do this. (looks like you are already familiar with the syntax at least on some level.)